# Identity for H space is the base point?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $(X,x_0)$ be a $H$-space with multiplication $\mu: X\times X\to X$.

Let $e$ be the identity with respect to $\mu$. Is it necessary that $e$ is the base point $x_0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necessary in what sense? Some people may require this as a convention (in which case it's necessary because by definition it's true), but otherwise consider the pointed space $(\mathbb{R}, 0)$ and the multiplication $\mu : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $(x,y) \mapsto xy$. This is an H-space (it's even a topological monoid), and $\mu$ is a pointed map, but $1 \neq 0$. It seems natural to want the unit to be the base point though.